# SvelteKit: redirect() not working on server without disabling ssr

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am using `+layout.server.ts` to redirect unauthenticated users from accessing authorized routes with this code:

```ts
/* +layout.server.ts */

export const load: PageServerLoad = async () => {
    // ...

    if (!isAuthenticatedUser && isAccessingAuthorizedRoute) {
        throw redirect(300, "/sign-in");
    }
}
```

But when I tested it by accessing an **authorized url** (let's say `/user/profile`), the browser gave me this error:

[image: See the error here]

I didn't know what was the problem. After some workarounds and debugging, I found out the error was caused by **server-side rendering**. Because when I turned off the **SSR** in `+layout.server.ts`, redirect worked as expected and **browser** didn't throw any error. To confirm it, I also tried disabling **SSR** for a single page and only that page was redirecting rightly.

Why is this happening? I want to use `redirect()` without disabling SSR.

**UPDATE**: I also tried **redirect()** in `+page.ts`, `+page.server.ts` and `+layout.ts`. The same error also happened there when **ssr** was enabled. I don't think my client-side js code is responsible.

Comment: Something else on your code has the error, the variable tagName is undefined and that is breaking on the client side.

Comment: I will make a fresh project and try to do the same thing with dummy code

Comment: @ShrijiKondan I have created a new project. There are 3 svelte pages without any client-side code. I did the same on it with dummy variable and logic. I also tried it in `+page.ts`, `+page.server.ts` and `+layout.ts`. But it doesn't work without disabling SSR. It is bothering me so much.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. the ssr fix works for me too but heaven knows why

Comment: Mysteriously (to me at least) throwing a redirect wouldn't work inside the try of a try-catch but it would if I placed it straight after.

Comment: @wkille well of course, redirects are made by `throw redirect(...)`, which is throwing an error. SvelteKit catches that error and handles the redirect, but if you catch the error in a try/catch block then SvelteKit can't handle it. See the note [in the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the problem. The culprit was the status code I was using for redirecting.

I was providing the wrong status code `300`:

```ts
// ...

    if (!isAuthenticatedUser && isAccessingAuthorizedRoute) {
        // Wrong!
        throw redirect(300, "/sign-in");
    }

// ...
```

Providing status code `307` solved the problem:

```ts
// From Svelte Documentation

export function load({ locals }) {
  if (!locals.user) {
        // Correct!
        throw redirect(307, '/login');
  }
}
```

Now it works fine with **SSR** enabled. There was no explanation why I have to use status code `307` to get it working in the documentation. I hope they will explain it in near future.

Comment: Glad you were able to sort this out. I think it should work with 301 and not 300. I am not sure about this.

Comment: Yeah, it does work with 301, 308.

Comment: This works on load and actions but I can't seem to get redirects to work on server hooks.

Answer (score 3):

Was facing the same problem and figured out the culprit is not the status code but rather the keyword **throw**, and it works fine on +page.server.ts.

Didn't work:

```
redirect(302, '/login')
```

Does work:

```
throw redirect(302, '/login')
```

Comment: With SvelteKit v2, this is now the opposite where `redirect()` alone works. You do not have to `throw` it. Source: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating-to-sveltekit-2